# How can i find a key name of value from the dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to find a key name of particular value of dictionary without any kind of loop. I can get key name of "S" but when the "SE" i found then i am not able to find the key name of "SE". here is my Dictionary

```
dictionary {
    East = S;
    North =     (
        NE,
        E,
        SE
    );
    south =     (
        SW,
        W,
        NW
    );
    west = N;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary is backwards. Convert it into the reverse of itself, so that S is a key and East is its value, NE is a key and North is its value, E is a key and North is its value, and so on. Now you have an instant lookup with no loop, as you say.

Comment: Thank you matt. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a [Dictionary Collection Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html), you can only find a value based on it's key. not a key based on it's value. This is because multiple keys could have the same value. (and that's not the purpose of a dictionary to begin with). Your only option would be to iterate over the dictionary and find all the keys for the value you're using.